# Creating and Exporting Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll refeshing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

Server has Microsoft Office 2003. Code is as below

at aspx Page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ExportExcel" runat="server" OnClick="ExportTabletoExcel_Click" OnClientClick="ExportTableJqueryMethod">ExportExcel</asp:LinkButton>
 </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ExportExcel" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

At Code behind

```
using Excel1= Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
protected void ExportTabletoExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Excel1.Application excelApp = new Excel1.Application();
...//Adding Data to Excel
excelWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Excel1.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
excelWorkBook.Close();

...//to download
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; > filename=ExportedExcel.xls");
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(path + ".xls");
}
```

In Web.config
`<add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"/>`

on click in Visual Studio the excel downloads just fine. But while running the same on server refreshes the page and no excel downloads.

Comment: Side note: Excel (and other Office Apps) are not supported in headless server environment. There is small (99%) chance that you will have a lot of issues getting it working in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you should check your server `IIS Pool` To `Enable 32-bit Applications` by going to your application pool. Right click and Go to **Advance settings**.

See below image,

[image]

It should be true.

Comment: also check it must be throwing some exception while downloading excel. furthermore, you must have to install ms office on server. otherwise this dll (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) won't be working on server.

Comment: Microsoft server 2003 is installed at server.

Comment: then have you checked by set above bit to `True` ?

Comment: Yes the Enable 32-Bit Applications is set to True

Comment: have you checked by debugging? It must be throwing some exception. by that only we can identify the error cause.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier the code is running just fine in Visual studio and Excel is downloading just fine without any exception or error. Its just not running over IIS so its not an issue of code.

Answer (score 0):

My code is as below that has implemented:

1. creating multiple sheets in excel workbook;
2. save the excel to a temp location in the web server;
3. and download the excel file from web application.

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
...
        private Excel.Workbook GenerateExcel()
        {
            string excelFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/TestFile.xlsx");
            Excel.Application excel = null;
            Excel.Workbook excelworkBook = null;
            try
            {
                excel = new Excel.Application();
                excel.Visible = false;
                excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

```
            //create two sheets AAA & BBB
            excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel.Worksheet excelSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.ActiveSheet;
            excelSheet1.Name = "AAA";
            Excel.Worksheet excelSheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.Worksheets.Add();
            excelSheet2.Name = "BBB";

            DataTable dataTable = GetTable();

            // now we resize the columns
            Excel.Range excelCellrange1 = excelSheet1.Range[excelSheet1.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet1.Cells[dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
            excelCellrange1.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            //Now fill excelSheet1 up with data
            int row = 1;
            int col = 1;
            foreach (DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++ )
                {
                    excelSheet1.Cells[row, col] = r[j];
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
            }

            //Now fill excelSheet2
            row = 1;
            col = 1;
            foreach (DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    excelSheet2.Cells[row, col] = r[j];
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            excelworkBook.SaveAs(excelFileName);
            excel.Quit();
            excel = null;
            excelworkBook = null;
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(excelFileName);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

        }
        return excelworkBook;
    }
```